# is there a way to disable being able to move icons on an ipod touch

Tags: ipod, ipod-touch

my 3yr old son loves using it, but everyday he manages to reorder everything, and places all the objects in 1 folder

I have found how to disable the delete ablitlity, but is there a way to prevent the object icons from being moved
thanks

Comment: This is a good question, there should be a lock icons option in the settings page. I noticed in the Apple Store that their iPads have the icons locked so customers cant delete or move apps. So Apple have a way of doing it, but it might be custom firmware.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to disable icon movement on a non-jailbroken iOS device.  As great as some of the "child-friendly" apps are, the stock UI of iOS devices is not designed to keep curious children at bay.

You could always load up an app for kids with built-in parent controls.  Then you'd want to protect the Home button from being pushed -- perhaps with a product like [BubCaps](http://bubcap.com/).